Applying HTML Attribute Conditionally
I am using HTML to create a set of cards containing vocabulary items, the properties of which I define in an array. These cards consist of a vocabulary item and a button containing a link to an image.
        const vocabCard= [
            {
                vocabulary: 'sled',
                hasImage: true,
            },
            {
                headword: 'ski',
                hasImage: false,
            },
        ];


    <div class="container">
        <div id="root"></div>
    </div>

    const categories = [...new Set(vocabCard.map((item) => { return item }))]
    let items = []


    const displayItem = (items) => {
        document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = items.map((item) => {
            var { vocabulary, hasImage } = item;
                return (
                    `<div class='box'>
                        <p class= "vocabBox">${vocabulary}         
                            <button class = "imagebutton" id = "imagebutton" onclick = location.href="xxx/${vocabulary}.png">
                                <span class="material-symbols-outlined">photo_camera</span>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </div>`
                )

I am trying to make the card only display the button if the value of hasImage is true. Otherwise, I would like the button to be hidden. Is there a way to apply the hidden or display: none attribute to the button conditionally? I have tried doing this with an if-statement (applied at the very end), but to no avail.
if (item.hasImage === false){
    document.getElementById('imagebutton').style.display = "none";


you should create a CSS class like .d-none { display: none; }. Then you can use JS to apply that class based on conditions such as element.classList.toggle('d-none', !item.hasImage). YOu should also create the cards with createElements

Rather than generating a button and trying to hide it afterwards, why not simply omit the generation when there is no image?

Your  code is going to result in multiple buttons with the same id. You should avoid that, and may well account for why your after-end if statement isn't doing what you want.

@Alohci What should I do in order to avoid getting multiple identical ids?

The second parameter of the callback function to the map function is an index. i.e. items.map((item, index) => { ... }. You could append that to the end of the id so the  button ids would be imagebutton0, imagebutton1, ...

Why not just do it like @BrettDonald sugested, something like return (\${vocabulary}` + (hasImage ? `<button ...>` : ``) + ``)` ...? Then you don't even need to bother with the IDs (which you currently only appear to be setting to be able to apply display:none) any more.
